# min function raising ValueError exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to use the built-in function *min* from Python 2.7.3 with the following list as an input:

```
[[-33.183271201814613, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-31.719166135222533, np.array([ 2.02657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-33.507228111267317, np.array([ 1.52657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-33.507228111267317, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.43957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-32.038950989011688, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.93957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-32.038950989011688, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.90703474])],
 [-31.815205800468107, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.40703474])]]
```

The problem is that I'm getting this *ValueError* exception. It's strange because *min* works on other arrays in the same form as this one, but this particular set of numerical values causes the error. The full exception:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Why is this happening? Could it be a bug in this version of Python?

Comment: That error doesn't come from `min`. Please show the code that causes this error.

Comment: What would you expect to be the minimum of this array?

Comment: Also, this appears to be a list rather than a (numpy) array.

Comment: where are the first values coming from in the sublist?

Comment: It is indeed a list, not an array. I edited the post to fix it. The minimum is supposed to be the sublist with the smallest first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Python sorts lists lexicographically. This means that when there is a tie for the first key, the 2nd key will be checked. In your case the second key correspond to numpy arrays, which mean that arrays of booleans are returned where single booleans are expected, raising `ValueError`. The problem disappears if your remove ties for the first key:

```
In [5]:

l = [[-33.183271201814613, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-31.719166135222533, np.array([ 2.02657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 #[-33.507228111267317, np.array([ 1.52657872, -1.68957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-33.507228111267317, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.43957646,  1.65703474])],
 #[-32.038950989011688, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.93957646,  1.65703474])],
 [-32.038950989011688, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.90703474])],
 [-31.815205800468107, np.array([ 1.77657872, -1.68957646,  1.40703474])]]
In [6]:

min(l)
Out[6]:
[-33.50722811126732, array([ 1.77657872, -1.43957646,  1.65703474])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, the problem was that I needed a key to sort the array using the first element only. Instead of using min(x), it was needed to use min(x, key=lambda i: i[0]).

Comment: so you wanted the min of  just the first element?

Comment: Exactly, should have made it clearer in the first post.